# Pager adapter with private methods without fragments in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Is it possible to user View pager without fragments. I google it, and all examples use fragments for view pager. I want to pager load only one item from my list, so I want to ask is it possible. Here is my code for main activity, and I want to use UpdateDisplay for viewpager. Any suggestions.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Button prev, next;
private TextView tv;
private int number = 0;
private ArrayList<Integer> numbers;
private ViewPager pager;
private MyPagerAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    prev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prevButton);
    prev.setOnClickListener(this);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);
    numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        numbers.add(i);
        Log.i("Sljedece elemente dodaje u listu", String.valueOf(i));
    }
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rezultatTextView);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    updateDIsplay(number);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.prevButton:
        number--;
        if (number==-1){
            number = 4;
        }
        updateDIsplay(number);
        break;
    case R.id.nextButton:
        number++;
        if (number==5){
            number = 0;
        }
        updateDIsplay(number);
        break;
    }

}

private void updateDIsplay(int z){

    tv.setText(String.valueOf(numbers.get(z)));

}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numbers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

yes it possible. Use a `PageAdapter`. When instantiateItem is called, you can inflate/instantiate your view, and this to the container. E.g:

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        TextView view = new TextView(PagerActivity.this);
        view.setText("Item "+position);
        view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, position * 50, position * 10, position * 50));

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you instead of adding new textview, use the one that I already declared. Only thing that I need is call method updateDIsplay when user swipe over the screen. So I dont need any other textview, only to call method updateDisplay(position). Can I do that in pager, or that is inposible.